# python maintain two different random instance

Tags: python

I am trying to do some anaylsis and for 'reasons' I want objects in my programm to each have their own seeds but no global seeds. Can I accomplish something like this ?

```
a = random.seed(seed1) 
b = random.seed(seed1)

for a in range(5) :
    print a.random(), b.random()
```

The expect output would be

```
0.23 0.23 
0.45 0.45 
0.56 0.56 
0.34 0.34
```

etc... 
Obviously a super contrived example -- These separate seed will be buried in objects and correspond to specific things. But first step is getting something like this to work.

How can I have python maintain multiple seeded randoms ?

Comment: I don't see why not, its not like you're sharing the memory between the two variables, have you tried coding it yet?

Comment: See `class Random`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

Comment: random doesnt have an init to return an object that I can see, which I used in my code because I wish it did. each time I call seed it is affecting a global seed based of my testing. I tired coding it and get a Nonetype has no random error since random.seed() doesnt actually retrun anything. this is python 2.7 btw

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Python's random number generator with a local seed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355985/how-to-use-pythons-random-number-generator-with-a-local-seed)

Comment: For your purposes, would it work to create a list of random numbers with a single random instance, and then pass that list down the line for re-use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use a `random.Random` class object.

```
from random import Random

a = Random()
b = Random()

a.seed(0)
b.seed(0)

for _ in range(5):
    print(a.randrange(10), b.randrange(10))

# Output:
# 6 6
# 6 6
# 0 0
# 4 4
# 8 8
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) states explicitly about your problem:

> The functions supplied by this module are actually bound methods of a
>   hidden instance of the `random.Random` class. You can instantiate your
>   own instances of `Random` to get generators that don’t share state.

Answer (score 0):

Then, this may help you:

```
>>> for _ in range(5): 
          rn=random.randint(1,100) 
          print(rn, rn)
```

Output is:
38 38

98 98

8 8

29 29

67 67

Answer (score -2):

I hope you are just looking for random numbers as mentioned in above output:

Here is some code. Please check, if can be helpful for you:

```
>>> for i in range(5):
        print(random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100))
```

Output will be as:

14 93

51 62

20 12

9 3

52 71

Comment: This is obviously not what OP is looking for: random pairs generated are different in your output, while there are expected to be the same.